# Shiny file Input accepting all file types

Tags: r, web-applications, shiny, shinyapps

I have created a form on Shiny which has fileInput button to upload only .pdf extension file.But while testing it i found that it's accepting all kind of file type however i have mentioned .pdf in accept parameter of fileInput shown in below codes:

```
 fileInput("fileid","Upload .pdf file only",multiple = FALSE, accept = c('.pdf'),width = "250px")
```

screenshot below that accepts all kind of file type:

accepting .xls file type

[image]

Accepting .csv file type:

[image]

I am looking for a solution that restrict user to upload .pdf file only and won't allow user to upload if some other file is selected.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can and must verify that yourself in your server function. `fileInput` gives you the MIME type and you can validate that has the correct type before you load it.

```
output$DisplayFileContent <- renderPrint({
  req(input$fileid)
  # Check for file type
  if (input$fileid$type != "application/pdf") stop("No PDF")
  
  pdffile <- readBin(con=input$file_input$datapath, what = 'raw',n=input$file_input$size)
  # ... more code to show file content
})
```